# How to save Username and Password at installation time in c# windows application?

Tags: c#, installation, settings

I am working on this C# Windows Application (.Net 3.5, VS 2008) for which i have to create an exe file, No issues till now,
The application consumes the betfair exchange API, which requires to "LOGIN" first thing to obtain a session token for any other service,

So my team-leader expects me to deploy the application in such a way that-

> 1. The Application should ask the client for Username and Password at installation time
> 2. If the user enters Username and Password, the application launches directly every time and uses the supplied username and password to log
>      in to the web service automatically.
> 3. If the user does not enters USER/Pass at installation time,then after installation the application must ask for username password each
>      time it is launched.

So my main query is:
How to get and store the username/password at installation time

i tried to write it in the app.config but it messes up with my web service settings somehow :/

Comment: Are you absolutely sure you want to store a password?

Comment: Is it a strict requirement that it is at installation time, or can you get away with showing the dialog at the first startup of the application? Both are certainly possible, but it is more cumbersome to have custom actions done during installation.

Comment: he wants it done at installation time only, i could not figure out how to do that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a couple of things to note.

Firstly, app.config files are generally not considered secure media, so you shouldn't be storing username/passwords in them (especially if they aren't encrypted)

A common place for storing these details in windows applications is inside the registry (which can be permissioned to reduce security risks).

All passwords should be stored in an encrypted format. Unfortunately given that this needs to be used vs an external system this encryption will need to be reversible.

Comment: +1, this is a useful notice. My addition is that always reuse what Windows offers, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1018575/login-dialog-for-windows-client-application

Comment: i haven't used registry ever before...can i store the credentials in a registry at installation time?? any tutorial or code snippet would help please....:/

Comment: @Samy000rathore Take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5e7chcf.aspx and here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4808/All-you-wanted-to-know-about-the-Registry-with-C-P

Comment: thanxx but anathor problem is what if the user does not have permisson to create registry??

Comment: Registry settings require elevated permissions (in modern OS's) your installer should be elevating to execute anyway as elevation is also required to write to program files

Answer (score 1):

I think that you can do it with a slightly different approach :

- Create an Installer program that will install your program
- At the end of the installation launch your program with the switch credentials (`/credentials`)
- This command line switch will allow the user to input and save authentication credentials

You can save the credentials on the [settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zszyc6e) app.config file for the current user ... 
Of course you will have to develop all the logic(form, ecc) linked to the `/credentials` option .

Comment: i am unaware of the use of (/credential) , can u hint me in the correct usage direction please :|